# HTML5 - Section or Div?

Tags: html

I am learning HTML 5 - going pretty smoothly.

My question is that I have a home page, header, menu and below this 3 content blocks, evenly spaced. They each contain various copy, with header text. For example,

Column 1

About Us
Lore Ipsum...

Our Advantage
Lore Ipsum...

Column 2

Our Products
Lore Ipsum...

Column 3

Contact Form

Twitter Feed

Contact Us
Lore Ipsum...

What is the best markup for this? Normally I would but each column in a div. Would this be best?

```
<div id="column1">
     <section>
     <h2>About Us</h2>
    <p>Lore Ipsum...</p>
     </section>
     <section>
     <h2>Our Advantage</h2>
     <p>Lore Ipsum...</p>
     </section>
</div>

<div id="column2">
     <section>
     <h2>Our Products</h2>
     <p>Lore Ipsum..</p>
     </section>
</div>

<div id="column3">
     <form...
     <div id="twitter">
          <script...>
     </div>
     <section>
     <h2>Contact Us</h2>
     <p>Lore Ipsum...</p>
     </section>
</div>
```

Comment: In section you should begin with `h1`, because `section` resets `hN` numbering.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say your posted code is fine, although personally I'd use `<header><h1></h1></header>`, instead of `<h2></h2>`, since the headings in this case are section headers (this is optional though).

More information on section headers can be found at:

- http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/
- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element

Comment: +1  more info on `<header>` here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element

Comment: Wrong. Heading elements are just as relevent in HTML5 as they are in HTML4. Header elements might even contain heading elements, or other content, too. So claiming header elements replace headings is seriously misinformed.

Comment: The preferred syntax for headers now is <header><hx></hx></header>. If you refer to centr0's link in the HTML5 rec, it says _"A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element)"_

Comment: @Karl - You're misinterpreting that quote. What that means is that if you have an hx element, and you need a richer header to the section than just the hx element (see the samples in the spec) then you can use the header element and the hx element should normally be one of the elements contained within it.

Comment: right so enclose the hx tags with <header></header> - Thanks guys. In my header I have <h1>business name</h1><h2>tagline</h2> - with multiple hx tags - that is when you use <hgroup>, correct?

Comment: @GregB - Correct. Although there remains a doubt about the future of the `<hgroup>` element. There is an open bug with the W3C HTML5 Working Group calling for its replacement with something more intuitive. The change has a lot of support within the WG but is unlikely to be formally addressed until the summer at the earliest.

Comment: @Alohci - I don't think that I am, although it does say that it is optional, which I didn't include in my first comment. It's perfectly valid (both syntactically and semantically) to wrap headings in header tags when they _are_ the section header though. When I updated my portfolio to HTML5, I tended to find that many of my section headers had time tags for blog entries and such, so for consistency I felt it better to wrap all section headers in `<header></header>` tags, even when the only content was a `<hx></hx>` tag. Doing it that way simplified things quite a lot for me, CSS particularly.

Comment: @GregB - That is correct, although like @Alohci said, <hgroup> elements are at risk of being dropped from HTML5, and are in my opinion unnecessary.

Comment: Sounds like drop <hgroup> for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `<article>` element instead of the `<section>` element, at least for "About Us" and "Our Advantage". These are almost certainly going to be syndicatable units of content so  `<article>` is more appropriate. Possibly for the other sections too, but it really depends on what the lorem ipsum text says.

Otherwise, what you've got is good. `<h2>`s for your headings are fine if that's what you want to use. Neither `<h1>` nor `<header>` are giving you anything extra.

Comment: 'but it really depends on what the lorem ipsum text says.' - I do not get the idea here 100%, and will do more research. H1s do not add because they no longer carry the weight that they once did? And using <header> or <hgroup> is not necessary either?

Comment: @GregB - May I recommend to you this HTML5 Doctor site: http://html5doctor.com/article-archive/ . There's good descriptions of all these elements and explanations of which to use where. The overriding point to understand is that HTML is a *semantic* mark-up language. In semantic terms, having a header element whose sole content is a single hx element is simply saying "This is a heading. This is a heading." It's just repetition. ...

Comment: ... To understand the relationship between hgroup, h1, h2 inside a sectioning element you need to get to grips with the outlining algorithm. See here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#outline . In that, the rank of the headings are related *relative* to one another, rather than by absolute value, so inside a sectioning element, an h2 when there's no h1 is semantically the same as an h1 - it's the top ranked heading.

Comment: ... In terms of why it matters what the lorem ipsum text says - my take on article vs section is that if you have a single coherent unit of content, that's an article. If you have a bag of related units that's a section. In the case of "Our Products" that's plural, so maybe you have a bag of descriptions of each of your products - a section - or maybe you have a description of how great your products are in general. That would be an article.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks a lot for those links, they are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done the same as you. As long as the sections in each div aren't strongly related. In that case I would change the divs to sections that contains sub-sections. Divs are still valid in HTML5 but are more of general block level containers.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the div? It serves no function from what I can tell. All the section elements can be styled as they are except 'column3', perhaps.

Comment: They format the blocks, add padding and float so they line up horizontally in a row properly - Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @GregB - Add padding and float to the SECTIONS so they line up horizontally in a row properly. The div is redundant.

Comment: I will look into that. The <divs> hold multiple articles though, and float left, i.e. 3 vert. div columns in a row, each containing multiple article tags.