# Content from section is pushing into another section

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap.

This is what my code displays in my web browser in desktop format: 
[image]

The gist of my problem is shown here:  http://jsfiddle.net/6x6c4qdb/

```
<section id="prices">
<p>Pricing Table Section </p>
</section>
<section id="contact">
<p> Contact Info </p>
</section>
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to stop content from my pricing tables from pushing into other sections when I decrease the browser window size into "mobile-view".  Is there a "word wrap" like or a content folding way in CSS or is this done through jquery? I just want the pricing tables to stay in the white section in the mobile view.

Comment: Word wrap is available word-wrap : break-word

Comment: Where would I put this in css? on the section itself? or on the pricing tables?

Comment: You mean you don't want media query. you want all of them in same line even on mobile? or

Comment: I want the pricing tables to stay in their section.  Is what you suggested the best way to do it?

Comment: You're html is structured incorrectly. You're missing some closing tags etc. I'm trying to fix the fiddle...stand by...

Comment: Thank you for identifying my problem and helping me fix it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `bootstrap` to create the structure, and put your things within that structure. When you change the structure, by adding dom elements in the middle of bootstraps structure, or outside of it, the structure breaks.

Here's the demo fiddle fixed:
[**Fiddle updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/6x6c4qdb/1/)

HTH

-Ted

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I tried your way from the fiddle.  The pricing tables do stay inside their white section, of which I did say that I wanted.  But, now I can't add anything to contact page.  Few questions, why didn't you close the prices section with a </section> tag?  Why did you put the div classes from the contact area outside of the contact section?

Comment: I did have a container class further up in my code, I just didn't post the whole code on fiddle.

Comment: Ah--create a fiddle with the whole code. That would help narrow it down from things like tags missing because of a partial code sample. You can just update the existing fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

I made some editing  [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/afwcq57w/1/) i think bootstrap should be the best option for you. the one's i labeled !important is just to replace bootstrap default setting without tampering with the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-12 padding-top pref-margin">
    <div class="col-md-4 pref-margin">
       <div class="panel panel-default border-r">
            <div class="panel-body no-padding">
            <div class="panel-content-head"> Proj 1</div>
            <div class="panel-content-body">
                <div class="price-body">
                    <li class="plan-price">
                        <strong>$125</strong>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-content-foot">
                <ul class="features">
                          <li>
                          Feature 1 Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
                          </li>
                          <li>
                          Feature 2 Blah blah blah blah
                          </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pref-margin">
             <div class="panel panel-default border-r">
            <div class="panel-body no-padding">
            <div class="panel-content-head"> Proj 1</div>
            <div class="panel-content-body">
                <div class="price-body">
                    <li class="plan-price">
                        <strong>$125</strong>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-content-foot">
                <ul class="features">
                           <li>
                        Feature 1 blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Feature 2 blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Feature 3 blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pref-margin">
             <div class="panel panel-default border-r">
            <div class="panel-body no-padding">
            <div class="panel-content-head"> Proj 1</div>
            <div class="panel-content-body">
                <div class="price-body">
                    <li class="plan-price">
                        <strong>$125</strong>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-content-foot">
                <ul class="features">
                          <li>
                        Feature 1 blah blah blah blah blah
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Feature 2 blah blah blahblahb lbhal
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Feature 3 blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Feature 4 blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Feature 5 blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Feature 6 blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
.pref-margin
{
    margin-right: -0px !important;
    margin-right: -0px !important;
    padding: 20px 1px !important;
}
}
.padding-top
{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.no-padding
{
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.border-r
{
    border-radius: 6px !important;
}
body {
    font-family: Helvetica,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:1.428571429;
    color:#333;
    background-color:#fff;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;

}
.panel-content-head
{
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #3d3d3d;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.price-body{
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: table;
}
li.plan-price {
  border-top: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}
.features
{
    border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

Comment: Now I really feel bad about not putting my entire code up in the first place.  Honestly, I didn't see the value of using media queries, but after seeing what you did with my pricing tables, the change in size is a whole lot smoother than what I originally had going on.  How did you get the line height so exact? After the browser changes beyond the max-width of 400, will it go back to its originally state in desktop mode, like in the picture I first posted? Thank you for your expertise.

Comment: do you want everything to be in desktop mode?

Comment: No, I don't. I just want the website to be mobile friendly. It's just the only thing that is messing up the design in the "mobile view" are the pricing tables, of which you have illustrated gracefully to correct.

Comment: okay if i answered your question please mark it as answered. And for the Max-width of 400. its to adjust it for those browsing with a lower screen size.

Comment: While your code makes the transition between size changes go a whole lot smoother, it's still not keeping those pricing boxes out of the next section.  Thus, I won't mark my question as answered.

Comment: whats actually do you want with your price box?

Comment: The positioning of the pricing tables was a symptom of a larger problem on the website, and I've already figured it out what was wrong.  Thank you for the tip, though. I was able to replicate it on the website, and it looked great.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! :) I stripped the content of the page and replaced it with a whole bunch of Lorem ipsum paragraphs and colored the font in each section a different color. By doing this, I wanted to see where the bleeding was happening. It turns out **all** of the sections were bleeding!  I couldn't see how bad the bleeding got until the third section, the pricing tables. Armed with this information, I checked out these resources on StackOverflow:

[HTML5 - Section or Div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130175/html5-section-or-div?rq=1)

[Bootstrap and html5 - section or div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298890/bootstrap-and-html5-section-or-div)

Sections tags(I guess in Bootstrap), by themselves, don't format, but divs do.  I just 'fortified' my sections with div tags. Although, this has produced a new problem in the dot navigation bar and Internet Explorer, these problems will probably turn into a new questions here in SO if I can't find the resources.  Thank you for the help, SO and users, especially the two who attempted.